# How can i get the members of a project of BIM 360 by forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I want to get the members of a project of BIM 360,but I can't find the http request.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I searched, there are POST APIs(https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/) to add a user or multiple users to a BIM360 project, but it does not provide the API to get the users of a project. We have logged this wish to our internal system.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Comment: Currently, it's already on track, but still work in progress. sorry for not bring a good news.

Comment: I'm seeing following comments on that thread: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/reading-users-in-a-project/td-p/7564021. "An API for managing users in projects, including user management in Design Collaboration and retrieving the list of users in a project  - is on the near term roadmap. Please stay tuned to Forge newsletter for updates on these APIs in the coming months." ... It's been over 4 months that it was posted, so what it is that you guys call "coming months"